# Dynamic function creation in classes

Tags: python

How can I dynamically create functions in a class in python so that I can do;

```
client = Client()
client.dynamic_function()
client.another_dynamic_function(params=123)
```

`dynamic_function` needs also needs to accept options that I can use when calling it.

Comment: What are the functions supposed to *do*? If you don't define them before you call them, you can't do anything that isn't much more easily defined and understood than defining a single fixed method that takes the "name" of your dynamic function as an argument.

Comment: @chepner usage being lots of calls to different parts of an api, where example you want to create the functions in a loop. See answers below for an example. Note that I answered my own question, as this is more of a "good to know" solution for those who didnt know this

Answer (score 0):

This will make you able to do that

```
class Client(object):

    @classmethod
    def _register(cls, name, **create_kwargs):
        def func(**kwargs):
          # Call your dynamic things in here...
          return kwargs

        def call(self, **kwargs):
            print('calling dynamic function {name}, created with ({create_kwargs})) results being: {result}'.format(name=name, create_kwargs=create_kwargs, result=func(**kwargs)))

        call.__name__ = name
        setattr(cls, name, call)

Client._register('dynamic1')
Client._register('dynamic2', option=123)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  client = Client()
  client.dynamic1()
  client.dynamic1(something=111)
  client.dynamic2()
  client.dynamic2(something=222)
  print(dir(client))
```

Producing the output:

```
calling dynamic function dynamic1, created with ({})) results being: {}
calling dynamic function dynamic1, created with ({})) results being: {'something': 111}
calling dynamic function dynamic2, created with ({'option': 123})) results being: {}
calling dynamic function dynamic2, created with ({'option': 123})) results being: {'something': 222}
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_register', 'dynamic1', 'dynamic2']
```

A real-world implementation (which they are not using anymore) is located at [here](https://github.com/zulip/zulip/blob/1.4.1/api/zulip/__init__.py#L510-L527). Based on the [commitlog](https://github.com/zulip/zulip/commit/efc2d1a675150d84dca99119bc135df107225724#diff-7e0a44740337e27c7081561d4f56c175), the reason being `This allows us to add docstrings and stricter mypy annotations.`.

There might be a more pythonic way to do this. But this works fine as well :)